# Working through Eloquent JavaScript exercise

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Im studying the book "eloquent javascript" Im having trouble noting the rest of this excerise. Plus I dont understand why in the for loop "i' has to be half of array.length.  You can see I'm trying to note every step to see exactly what it does.

any help would be appericated

```
//function named reverseArrayInPlace with one parameter array
function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
  // foor loop, intialize i at 0, i less than half array length, i plus one 
  //for ever iteration of the loop
  for (let i = 0; i < Math.floor(array.length / 2); i++) {
    //let old (called old because we are going back to original)
    //equal array [current array item] we are on
    let old = array[i];
    // array [current item] equals..
    array[i] = array[array.length - 1 - i];
    array[array.length - 1 - i] = old;
  }
  return array;
}
```

Comment: Because once you've swapped the first half of the array elements with the second half... you don't need to do any more swapping.

Comment: If you don't stop halfway through, you'll swap everything back into its original place when you process the second half of the array.

Comment: Not only would you not need to, it would actually be counter productive. You would end up with the array in its original order

Comment: thanks guys-- can you help me note the rest of the for loop as well. having trouble understanding the logic

Comment: The code is swapping the values of array elements, in place, symmetrically about it's mid point. The standard way of swapping values held in two places, say in `x` and `y`, is to take a temporary copy (`old`) of `x`, set `x` to `y` and then set `y` to `old`.  Without taking a copy of what `x` was before being overwritten, the code can't know what to set `y` to afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think this one is more "eloquent" ?  ;-)

```js
const reverseArrayInPlace = arr =>
  {
  let
    len  = arr.length
  , half = len >> 1      // integer division by 2
    ;
  for (let x=0, y=--len ; x < half ; x++, y--)
    [ arr[x], arr[y] ] = [ arr[y], arr[x] ];   // swap array values in ES7
  }

let
  myArr_A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0 ]
, myArr_B = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ]
, myArr_C = ['one']
  ;
reverseArrayInPlace( myArr_A )
reverseArrayInPlace( myArr_B )
reverseArrayInPlace( myArr_C )

console.log(JSON.stringify(myArr_A))
console.log(JSON.stringify(myArr_B))
console.log(JSON.stringify(myArr_C))
```